# Delete rows on 2 criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have copied over a spreadsheet from a form response to another sheet. The first row contains headers that are used by my pivot.

The rows from this destination sheet should be deleted unless:

Column c = today's date
AND column e = 'Show - Sale'

I have managed to get criteria workong on column e but not on column c (could be down to the way it's formatted??).

I also can't seem to stop it deleting the header row!

Cheers

Comment: Posting minimal parts of your code that reproduce the issue will help us help you. As it is, there's no way to tell what you might be doing incorrectly, as there's no way for us to know what you're doing!

Answer (score 1):

One equal sign in JavaScript is an assignment operator.  For conditional checks in JavaScript you must use either double equal signs or triple equal signs.